# How to remove first string part of a transcript in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I got a transcript column in a large date frame and I want to remove/delete from the beginning of the transcript not useful messages, something like hi or hello if the user type it.

Transcript examples:

> "User : Hello \nBot : Hi there. \User : Order status.\nBot : Your order status is your orders tab. \nUser : representative."

> "User : Agent please.\nBot : Waiting time is longer than usual."

Output should remove the not useful part of the transcript, including the bot response and get the following output:

> "User : Order status.\nBot : Your order status is your orders tab. \nUser : representative."

> "User : Agent please.\nBot : Waiting time is longer than usual."

The second transcript remained untouched because it has not Hi or hello.

This is what I have so far:

```
df['Transcript'].str.split('\User').str.contains('hi|hello')
```

Comment: please provide the output of `df['Transcript'].head().to_list()` for reproducibility

Answer (score 1):

First, you can save the split of messages into a var, and use regex to do the trick.

So using pure python, you can try something like this:

```py
messages = [
    'hello, bot',
    'How are you going?',
    'Are you here?',
    'i want know about my order status'
]
ignored = 'hello|how are you?|are you here?'
output = []

for msg in messages:
    if not re.match(ignored, msg.lower()):
        output.append(msg)

print(output)
```

The output should be:

```
['i want know about my order status']
```

Comment: Is there a way to append the results to a new column in the data frame?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
out = df['col'].str.replace(':', r':\User *').str.split(r':').explode()
(out[~(out.str.contains('Hello|Hi') | out.eq('User '))].str.replace(r'*', ':')
 .groupby(level=0).sum()
 .str.replace(r' \User :', ':'))
```

Output:

```
0    \User : Order status.\nBot: Your order status ...
1    \User : Agent please.\nBot: Waiting time is lo...
Name: col, dtype: object
```